# Programmable latch

Tags: microcontroller, power, circuit-design, power-electronics, latch

For my especial "power on" design, I need to have programmable latch that maintains its state even when power gone!. The uC power will be gone but I need to set up a latch or IC when it receive its power, comes back to its programmed state e.g. "1" but can be come back to "0" when it becomes necessary by programing.

[image]

First, when the push button starts turning on circuit, uC will keep the circuit on. But when there is no accessibility to switch, there should be a programmable element that by applying Vdd, feed the D3 and should be possible to program it again to first state.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just use EEPROM in the MCU (as many MCUs  have) or external EEPROM? You can have the MCU start, retrieve the state and then sleep if you want.

Comment: Coin cell battery backup is the common simple solution for static volatile memory latches or non-volatile memory if you have flash or EEPROM.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easy and costly thing would be to use a latching relay. It does the job and consumes nothing. Otherwise usually you use some kind of non-volatile memory. FRAM (ferroelectric ram) would be perfect since has no endurance issues. Other kinds of memories are available like EEPROM or even flash (often there's some accessible for use in the MCU).

The issue, from what you say, is that you need something that actually starts up the MCU when powered up (like in the PC BIOS 'state on power loss' option). This is not easy since it's usually done with dedicated circuits. Look for "pushbutton controller" in the manufacturer catalogs.

I implemented something like that using an LTC2955 (which *always* turn on at power on) in this way:

- Power goes on and the controller switches up the regulators
- First thing the MCU checks if the power on is from initial supply or if a button was pressed
- If it was from initial supply it checks if there's the 'autostart' option set in configuration
- If it isn't it request a poweroff from the controller, otherwise it starts and do it stuff.

You only have an extremely brief power on to check the option on the initial power on, then everything is handled by the controller. Maybe if you look around there is something with a programmable option in the controller, they make new parts every day.